# Illustrator: how to open SVG with embedded font

Tags: adobe-illustrator, fonts, svg, web-fonts

I have an SVG file with an embedded Chinese font. The font in the SVG file can be displayed successfully in the web browsers, but when I want to use Illustrator to edit the SVG file, the font just can't be displayed, it sais it doesn't have the coresponding font file. Doesn't Illustrator support this kind of SVG embed font?

The full SVG code is:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<!-- This file was generated by dvisvgm 2.1.1 -->
<svg height='800.236pt' version='1.1' viewBox='-35.1495 -33.9496 263.776 800.236' width='263.776pt' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink'>
<style type='text/css'>
<![CDATA[
@font-face{font-family:nf0;src:url(data:application/x-font-ttf;base64,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) format('truetype');}
@font-face{font-family:nf1;src:url(data:application/x-font-ttf;base64,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) format('truetype');}
text.f0 {font-family:nf0;font-size:14.3462px}
text.f1 {font-family:nf1;font-size:11.9552px}
]]>
</style>
<g id='page1'>
<text class='f0' x='-35.1495' y='-20.36'>SEE BELOWWWWWW</text>
<text class='f1' x='222.649' y='762.927'>1</text>
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: where the 'SEE BELOWWWWWW' should be the Chinese word, but stackexchange banned it

Answer (score 1):

You must have a font installed on your computer in order to edit it in graphics programs.

When you see a font embedded in a .svg or.pdf, only those characters are included, and because of licensing they are not available to edit. Only the person who owns a font file is allowed to use it, so the rules go.

So you need to obtain the font file, install it on your computer, then open the .svg.